# C "Battleship" program non-statistical output after 10k+ iterations

Tags: c, algorithm, statistics, probability

I'm trying to duplicate the findings at http://thevirtuosi.blogspot.com/2011/10/linear-theory-of-battleship.html. His finding is that the observation / empirical probability map for ships of subsequently smaller size forces them out from the center, where the ships of increasing size tend to gather.
Whereas his results are symmetric between vertical and horizontal axes, the code I have written yields results where the horizontal axis gets noticeably more placement in ships - even though I am doing everything I can think of to thoroughly randomize the process between whether vertical or horizontal goes first. This asymmetry persists at any size of map. The minimum code to communicate the problem is 171 lines. Is this forum appropriate for this? This is not homework, work, or class related. I just have an interest in Battleship algorithms. The output is actual number of iterations that placed a certain ship in a certain spot, a percentage of such, and an ASCII character map of such - for easier eyeballing of asymmetries. Any direction appreciated.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
clock_t start, end;
double cpu_time_used;
srand(time(NULL));
int obstruction;
int done;
int waysVert=0;
int waysHorz=0;
int counter=0;
int vertCounter=0;
int horzCounter=0;
int iGuess=0;
int jGuess=0;
int shipType=0;
int shotCounter=0;
int hitCounter=0;
int shipCellCounter=0;
int guessCounter=0;
int lenShip=0;
int highestProb=0;
int highestOccur=0;
int iteration=0;
int i=0;//x dimension
int j=0;//y dimension
int k=0;//z dimension and information dimension
int n=0;//number dimension
char shipChar;
char shipName[20]="";
char shipList[]="ABCDS";//question for later: How does placement order affect heat map?
int numberShips=strlen(shipList);
int jShipStart=0;
int iShipStart=0;
int polShipDir=0;
int biasShipDir=0;
int jShipDir=0;
int iShipDir=0;
int NUM_COLS=10;//x dimension
int NUM_ROWS=10;//y dimension
int NUM_LEVS=21;//[0,7] Theoretical Prob. [10,16] Empirical Prob. 20 Presentation Level
char                grid[NUM_LEVS][NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS];
long int empiricalGrid[NUM_LEVS][NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS];


for(k=0;k<NUM_LEVS;k++){for(j=0;j<NUM_ROWS;j++){for(i=0;i<NUM_COLS;i++){           grid[k][j][i]=0;}}}//initialize 1-byte levels
for(k=0;k<NUM_LEVS;k++){for(j=0;j<NUM_ROWS;j++){for(i=0;i<NUM_COLS;i++){empiricalGrid[k][j][i]=0;}}}//initialize 4-byte levels
k=20;//k=20 is the presentation level
//for(j=0;j<NUM_ROWS;j++){for(i=0;i<NUM_COLS;i++){grid[k][j][i]='~';}}//initialize water character (first time, single run)

start = clock();
for(iteration=0;iteration<50000;iteration++){//has run at 50000000 iteration//could put scaling onto the printout using digit length of iterations
    for(j=0;j<NUM_ROWS;j++){for(i=0;i<NUM_COLS;i++){grid[k][j][i]='~';}}//initialize water character (every time, in loop)

    //PLACEMENT ROUTINE FOR-LOOP AND DO-WHILE LOOP
    for (shipType = 0; shipType < strlen(shipList); shipType++){
        shipChar=shipList[shipType];

        switch(shipChar){
        case 'A':lenShip=5;break;
        case 'B':lenShip=4;break;
        case 'C':lenShip=3;break;
        case 'D':lenShip=2;break;
        case 'S':lenShip=3;break;//since ran out of 3, think low number as in low elevation, beneath any other ships 
        }
        shipCellCounter+=lenShip;
        k=20;

        do{
            jShipStart=0;
            iShipStart=0;
            polShipDir=0;
            biasShipDir=0;
            jShipDir=0;
            iShipDir=0;
            obstruction=0;//printf("\nSet to no obstruction to %d\n",obstruction);
            if(rand()%2==0){
                jShipStart=rand()%NUM_ROWS;//printf("jShipStart %d starting row (0-%d)\n",jShipStart,NUM_ROWS-1);//
                iShipStart=rand()%NUM_COLS;//printf("iShipStart %d starting col (0-%d)\n",iShipStart,NUM_COLS-1);//
            }
            else{
                iShipStart=rand()%NUM_COLS;//printf("iShipStart %d starting col (0-%d)\n",iShipStart,NUM_COLS-1);//
                jShipStart=rand()%NUM_ROWS;//printf("jShipStart %d starting row (0-%d)\n",jShipStart,NUM_ROWS-1);//
            }
            polShipDir  = (rand()%2) * 90;//printf("polShipDir %d degrees\n",polShipDir);//polarity 00 deg => prop horz, 90 = prop vert
            biasShipDir = (rand()%2) * (-2) + 1;//printf("biasShipDir %d\n",biasShipDir);

            if(rand()%2==0){
                if( polShipDir==90 && jShipStart  > lenShip-1){ jShipDir=(rand()%2) * (-2) + 1; }
                if( polShipDir==90 && jShipStart <= lenShip-1){ jShipDir=(rand()%2) * (-2) + 1; }
                if( polShipDir== 0 && iShipStart  > lenShip-1){ iShipDir=(rand()%2) * (-2) + 1; }
                if( polShipDir== 0 && iShipStart <= lenShip-1){ iShipDir=(rand()%2) * (-2) + 1; }
            }
            else{
                if( polShipDir== 0 && iShipStart <= lenShip-1){ iShipDir=(rand()%2) * (-2) + 1; }
                if( polShipDir== 0 && iShipStart  > lenShip-1){ iShipDir=(rand()%2) * (-2) + 1; }
                if( polShipDir==90 && jShipStart <= lenShip-1){ jShipDir=(rand()%2) * (-2) + 1; }
                if( polShipDir==90 && jShipStart  > lenShip-1){ jShipDir=(rand()%2) * (-2) + 1; }
            }

            for(n=0;n<lenShip;n++){//Check to see if ANY part of the ship runs off map.
                if(rand()%2==0){
                    if( polShipDir== 90 && jShipStart + n * jShipDir >= NUM_ROWS || polShipDir==  0 && iShipStart + n * iShipDir >= NUM_COLS ){
                        obstruction=1;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    if( polShipDir==  0 && iShipStart + n * iShipDir >= NUM_COLS || polShipDir== 90 && jShipStart + n * jShipDir >= NUM_ROWS){
                        obstruction=1;
                    }
                }
            }

            for(n=0;n<lenShip;n++){//Check to see if ANY part of the ship DID NOT hit water.
                if( grid [ k ] [ jShipStart + n * jShipDir ] [ iShipStart + n * iShipDir ] != '~' ){
                obstruction=1;
                }//ANY single obstruction means start over for this ship.
            }

            if(obstruction==0){//If prior loop HAS NOT resulted in ANY obstruction: THEN assign this ship
                for(n=0;n<lenShip;n++){
                    grid [ k ] [ jShipStart + n * jShipDir ] [ iShipStart + n * iShipDir ] = shipChar;
                }
            }
        }
        while(obstruction==1);
    }

    for(i=0;i<NUM_COLS;i++){for(j=0;j<NUM_ROWS;j++){
             if(grid[20][j][i]=='A'){empiricalGrid[15][j][i]++;}
        else if(grid[20][j][i]=='B'){empiricalGrid[14][j][i]++;}
        else if(grid[20][j][i]=='C'){empiricalGrid[13][j][i]++;}
        else if(grid[20][j][i]=='S'){empiricalGrid[10][j][i]++;}//DONT CHANGE THIS RECORD OF SEQUENCE ANYWHERE ELSE. KEEP IT HERE.
        else if(grid[20][j][i]=='D'){empiricalGrid[12][j][i]++;}
        }
    }
}
end = clock();
cpu_time_used = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

for(k=16;k>=10;k--){for(j=0;j<NUM_ROWS;j++){for(i=0;i<NUM_COLS;i++){if(highestOccur<=empiricalGrid[k][j][i]){highestOccur=empiricalGrid[k][j][i];}}}}
printf("Level %d Highest occurance = %d\n",k,highestOccur);

for(j=0;j<NUM_ROWS;j++){for(i=0;i<NUM_COLS;i++){printf("%10lu", empiricalGrid[15][j][i]);}printf("\n");}printf("A\n");
for(j=0;j<NUM_ROWS;j++){for(i=0;i<NUM_COLS;i++){printf("%10lu", empiricalGrid[14][j][i]);}printf("\n");}printf("B\n");
for(j=0;j<NUM_ROWS;j++){for(i=0;i<NUM_COLS;i++){printf("%10lu", empiricalGrid[13][j][i]);}printf("\n");}printf("C\n");
for(j=0;j<NUM_ROWS;j++){for(i=0;i<NUM_COLS;i++){printf("%10lu", empiricalGrid[12][j][i]);}printf("\n");}printf("D\n");
for(j=0;j<NUM_ROWS;j++){for(i=0;i<NUM_COLS;i++){printf("%10lu", empiricalGrid[10][j][i]);}printf("\n");}printf("S\n");
printf("Iterations: %d. CPU time used: %lf seconds. CLOCKS_PER_SEC = %d\n",iteration,cpu_time_used,CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

for(j=0;j<NUM_ROWS;j++){for(i=0;i<NUM_COLS;i++){printf("%2.2lf ", (double) empiricalGrid[15][j][i]/highestOccur);}printf("\n");}printf("A^\n");
for(j=0;j<NUM_ROWS;j++){for(i=0;i<NUM_COLS;i++){printf("%2.2lf ", (double) empiricalGrid[14][j][i]/highestOccur);}printf("\n");}printf("B^\n");
for(j=0;j<NUM_ROWS;j++){for(i=0;i<NUM_COLS;i++){printf("%2.2lf ", (double) empiricalGrid[13][j][i]/highestOccur);}printf("\n");}printf("C^\n");
for(j=0;j<NUM_ROWS;j++){for(i=0;i<NUM_COLS;i++){printf("%2.2lf ", (double) empiricalGrid[12][j][i]/highestOccur);}printf("\n");}printf("D^\n");
for(j=0;j<NUM_ROWS;j++){for(i=0;i<NUM_COLS;i++){printf("%2.2lf ", (double) empiricalGrid[10][j][i]/highestOccur);}printf("\n");}printf("S^\n");
printf("Iterations: %d. CPU time used: %lf seconds. CLOCKS_PER_SEC = %d\n",iteration,cpu_time_used,CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

for(j=0;j<NUM_ROWS;j++){for(i=0;i<NUM_COLS;i++){printf("%2c", 33+(int)(10*((double) empiricalGrid[15][j][i]/highestOccur)));}printf("\n");}printf("A^\n");
for(j=0;j<NUM_ROWS;j++){for(i=0;i<NUM_COLS;i++){printf("%2c", 33+(int)(10*((double) empiricalGrid[14][j][i]/highestOccur)));}printf("\n");}printf("B^\n");
for(j=0;j<NUM_ROWS;j++){for(i=0;i<NUM_COLS;i++){printf("%2c", 33+(int)(10*((double) empiricalGrid[13][j][i]/highestOccur)));}printf("\n");}printf("C^\n");
for(j=0;j<NUM_ROWS;j++){for(i=0;i<NUM_COLS;i++){printf("%2c", 33+(int)(10*((double) empiricalGrid[10][j][i]/highestOccur)));}printf("\n");}printf("S^\n");//SWITCH BACK
for(j=0;j<NUM_ROWS;j++){for(i=0;i<NUM_COLS;i++){printf("%2c", 33+(int)(10*((double) empiricalGrid[12][j][i]/highestOccur)));}printf("\n");}printf("D^\n");

printf("Iterations: %d. CPU time used: %lf seconds. CLOCKS_PER_SEC = %d\n",iteration,cpu_time_used,CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
printf("!=00s, \"=10s, #=20s, $=30s, %%=40s, &=50s, \'=60s, (=70s, )=80s, *=90s\n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `rand() % NUM_ROWS` is biased towards lower values (for *most* values of NUM_ROWS)

Comment: You really should adopt are more conventional coding style. This code is very hard to read for anyone but you. Hint: to make the code compact, use functions instead of omitting new lines.

Comment: You might also want to explain about using 15,14,13,10,12 vs 15,14,13,12,10 in different places.

Comment: @Lundin, I find the code is well formatted and compact, using column-based symmetry. Take 5 minutes to study it and you get his style. The "conventional style" will blow it up to several hundred lines of code and won't give you a better overview.

Comment: "The determined Real Programmer can write FORTRAN programs in any language." -- [Ed Post.](http://www.ee.ryerson.ca/~elf/hack/realmen.html)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any bugs that would produce the bias you're talking about, but I do see some unnecessary complication, and I can offer some suggestions:

- As suggested by wildplasser in the comments, using `%` to extract small random numbers from the C runtime library `rand()` often gives notoriously bad performance.  Try a stronger RNG, or even better, actual randomness from the likes of `/dev/urandom`.  At the very least, try using this for seeding another RNG.
- As a quick but not conclusive test, try changing `polShipDir  = (rand()%2) * 90;` to `polShipDir  = (1 - rand()%2) * 90;`.  Is the bias now for vertical ships?  If so, then the problem is definitely the RNG, since with a good RNG, the preceding two statements should be equivalent on average.
- In two separate places, you're unnecessarily randomising *the order in which you perform two tests whose order doesn't matter!*  First:

(need this line for formatting apparently...)

```
if(rand()%2==0){
            if( polShipDir==90 && jShipStart  > lenShip-1){ jShipDir=(rand()%2) * (-2) + 1; }
            if( polShipDir==90 && jShipStart <= lenShip-1){ jShipDir=(rand()%2) * (-2) + 1; }
            if( polShipDir== 0 && iShipStart  > lenShip-1){ iShipDir=(rand()%2) * (-2) + 1; }
            if( polShipDir== 0 && iShipStart <= lenShip-1){ iShipDir=(rand()%2) * (-2) + 1; }
        }
        else{
            if( polShipDir== 0 && iShipStart <= lenShip-1){ iShipDir=(rand()%2) * (-2) + 1; }
            if( polShipDir== 0 && iShipStart  > lenShip-1){ iShipDir=(rand()%2) * (-2) + 1; }
            if( polShipDir==90 && jShipStart <= lenShip-1){ jShipDir=(rand()%2) * (-2) + 1; }
            if( polShipDir==90 && jShipStart  > lenShip-1){ jShipDir=(rand()%2) * (-2) + 1; }
        }
```

can be simplified to

```
if( polShipDir==90){ jShipDir=(rand()%2) * (-2) + 1; }
if( polShipDir== 0){ iShipDir=(rand()%2) * (-2) + 1; }
```

Second, much the same happens in the loop beginning with the comment `//Check to see if ANY part of the ship runs off map.`.  (BTW, you don't need a loop for this test at all: it suffices to check whether the beginning and ending points of the ship are at valid locations.)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone for general suggestions.
Thank you wildplasser and j_random_hacker who mentioned the problems with rand().
I went and got a real random generator (http://www.makelinux.net/alp/046), the problem persisted, and I then found a programming error in my code. I had insufficient barriers to stop ships from word-wrapping off the right side and coming back one down on the left. That was causing the bias.
My probability maps with this fix and the same old rand() do reproduce the findings from the link mentioned, so that means to me that rand() is not "that" bad for my low level requirements.
I am happy to hear that I can improve that randomness if I need to.
Thanks again.

My map for (4-long) B now at 900000 (which tighten up at higher iteration). You can see where the ' outlines a shadow of the (5-long) A, and also where the % intrudes on the sides and interacts with &, another shadow of the (5-long) A.

```
    " # $ % % % % $ # "
    # $ % & % & & % $ #
    $ % & & & & & & % $
    % & & ' & & ' & & %
    % % & & & & ' & % %
    % % & & & & & & % %
    % & & ' & & ' & & %
    $ % & & & & & & % $
    # $ % & % % & % $ #
    " # $ % % % % $ # "
```